# Write same value to 2 different columns with JDBC Sink Connector

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

There are 2 columns that needs to be same in the table I want to sink on. Lets say columns are named as ID and PAYLOADID. But in the Kafka side, there are no seperate records for these columns. So, how can I configure my sink connector to write to these 2 columns from the same field in Kafka?

This is my connector config:

```
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
"tasks.max": "1",
"connection.user": "${file:/pass.properties:alm_user}",
"connection.password": "${file:/pass.properties:alm_pwd}",
"connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=****)(PORT=****))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=****)))",
"table.name.format": "SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME",
"topics": "MY_TOPIC",
"transforms": "TimestampConverter1",
"transforms.TimestampConverter1.target.type": "Timestamp",
"transforms.TimestampConverter1.field": "RECORDDATE",
"transforms.TimestampConverter1.format": "MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm:ss",
"transforms.TimestampConverter1.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"auto.create": "false",
"insert.mode": "insert",
"transforms": "rename",
"transforms.rename.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
"transforms.rename.renames": "payload:PAYLOADID, type:TYPE"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to write your own transform, or otherwise pre-process the topic, such that you can copy and rename one field to another while keeping the same field-value.